# How does Swift manage Arrays internally?

Tags: arrays, swift, arraylist

I would like to know how Swift managed arrays internally? [Apple's language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) only handles usage, but does not elaborate on internal structures.

As a Java-developer I am used to looking at "bare" arrays as a very static and fixed data structure. I know that this is not true in Swift. In Swift, other than in Java, you can mutate the length of an array and also perform insert and delete operations. In Java I am used to decide what data structure I want to use (simple arrays, ArrayList, LinkedList etc.) based on what operations I want to perform with that structure and thus optimise my code for better performance.

In conclusion, I would like to know how arrays are implemented in Swift. Are they internally managed as (double) linked lists? And is there anything available comparable to Java's Collection Framework in order to tune for better performance?

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://roopc.net/posts/2014/arrays-in-swift-beta-2/

Comment: You could try the Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find a lot of information on `Array` in the comment above it in the Swift standard library.  To see this, you can cmd-opt-click `Array` in a playground, or you could look at it in the unofficial [SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Array/) page.

To paraphrase some of the info from there to answer your questions:

Arrays created in Swift hold their values in a contiguous region of memory.  For this reason, you can efficiently pass a Swift array into a C API that requires that kind of structure.

As you mention, an array can grow as you append values to it, and at certain points that means that a fresh, larger, region of memory is allocated, and the previous values are copied into it.  It is for this reason that its stated that operations like append *may* be `O(n)` – that is, the worst-case time to perform an append operation grows in proportion to the current size of the array (because of the time taken to copy the values over).

However, when the array has to grow its storage, the amount of new storage it allocates each time grows exponentially, which means that reallocations become rarer and rarer as you append, which means the "amortized" time to append over all calls approaches constant time.

Arrays also have a method, `reserveCapacity`, that allows you to preemptively avoid reallocations on calling append by requesting the array allocate itself some minimum amount of space up front.  You can use this if you know ahead of time how many values you plan to hold in the array.

Inserting a new value into the middle of an array is also `O(n)`, because arrays are held in contiguous memory, so inserting a new value involves shuffling subsequent values along to the end.  Unlike appending though, this does not improve over multiple calls.  This is very different from, say, a linked list where you can insert in `O(1)` i.e. constant time.  But bear in mind the big tradeoff is that arrays are also randomly accessible in constant time, unlike linked lists.

Changes to single values in the array in-place (i.e. assigning via a subscript) should be `O(1)` (`subscript` doesn't actually have a documenting comment but this is a pretty safe bet).  This means if you create an array, populate it, and then don't append or insert into it, it should behave similarly to a Java array in terms of performance.

There's one caveat to all this – arrays have "value" semantics.  This means if you have an array variable `a`, and you assign it to another array variable `b`, this is essentially copying the array.  Subsequent changes to the values in `a` will not affect `b`, and changing `b` will not affect `a`.  This is unlike "reference" semantics where both `a` and `b` point to the same array and any changes made to it via `a` would be reflected to someone looking at it via `b`.

However, Swift arrays are actually "Copy-on-Write".  That is, when you assign `a` to `b` no copying actually takes place.  It only happens when one of the two variables is changed ("mutated").  This brings a big performance benefit, but it does mean that if two arrays are referencing the same storage because neither has performed a write since the copy, a change like a subscript assign does have a one-off cost of duplicating the entire array at that point.

For the most part, you shouldn't need to worry about any of this except in rare circumstances (especially when dealing with small-to-modest-size arrays), but if performance is critical to you it's definitely worth familiarizing yourself with all of the documentation in that link.

Comment: Is the internal storage of Array elements always contiguous? Then why does the comments to some methods like `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` say that *"If no such [contiguous] storage exists, it is first created."*. And why is there a separate ContiguousArray type? – Perhaps is this only relevant if the Array is bridged from NSArray.

Comment: Hmm good point.  I'm inferring the memory is always contiguous from the preamble part of the docs, but you're right, it's not 100% explicitly stated.  Perhaps the allocation of storage is deferred if there are no elements actually inserted yet, or in cases where it has only been initialized from a literal and not changed since?  I gather the `ContiguousArrayType` is specifically tuned for holding references – but I'm not sure of the specific reason for the name, which does imply `Array` isn't contiguous.  Perhaps they want to reserve the right to change `Array`'s implementation in the future.

Comment: This posting from the developer forum seems to cover it: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1013086#1013086.

Comment: Aha, thanks.  Have amended my answer to "Arrays created in Swift" accordingly rather than plunge into the whole question of ObjC interop...  :)

Comment: There's some further discussion of `Array` internals in the Swift talks [from WWDC14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

Comment: Bear in mind (can't recall which WWDC video covered what) that arrays underwent a dramatic change early in the beta but post WWDC which _could_ mean that info is out of date.

Comment: Great answer! Very comprehensive and very well explained. Thank you for your time and your kind response!!!

Comment: effective explanation and also i think it will good to understand importance of "isUniquelyReferenced" in swift collection types.