# Returning a sorted Swift Dictionary as parameter

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a function that I want to return a sorted dictionary

```
func sortDictonary()->[Int:String]
{
    let dic:[Int:String] = [ 1:"B", 0:"A", 2:"C" ]
    let sorted = dic.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0} )
    return sorted
}
```

however I get an error as follows:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[(key: Int, value: String)]' to return type '[Int : String]'
```

How can I convert the sorted items into a standard dictionary

Comment: I guess you can not guarantee the order of a standard dictionary, so, either I need to use the sorted dictionary type, or think of another way of solving my problem. I should have thought of that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334870/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25377177/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30054854/1187415, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to return a sorted dictionary

Stop wanting that. There is no such thing as a sorted dictionary. What you're doing creates an *array of pairs* sorted by the first of the pair (effectively, what used to be the key in the dictionary), and that is as good as it gets.

```
func sortDictonary()->[(Int,String)]
{
    let dic:[Int:String] = [ 1:"B", 0:"A", 2:"C" ]
    let sorted = dic.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0} )
    return sorted
}
```

Comment: There are sorted dictionary data structures... Not in the standard library, for some crazy reason, but they're quite ubiquitously available.

Comment: @Alexander That's as may be, but I find in fact that most people who say they need a sorted dictionary actually don't need one. Usually they are just disappointed at the order in which the dictionary prints, or similar...

Comment: Yep, although it's total sensible, for example, to have a Dictionary based table (headers are keys, which map to arrays of items under that heading) while still preserving constant time look ups.

Comment: @Alexander I don't see why. The usual table data source model is an array of sections each of which contains an array of rows, and since you are going to be asked for the information by index number, arrays make sense. Lookup in an array by index is not worse than lookup in a dictionary by key; in fact, it's probably better, because we can go right to the location in memory. An array is a contiguous buffer, not some kind of double-linked-list that needs to be walked for every access (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945725/341994).

Comment: I'm aware, but most models are structured as I described. Having an array of "section" objects, each containing an array of child objects, is  not common outside of table sources. It would be ideal to be able to parse some API's output into a sorted dict, and have deterministic index-based look up